# onclick menu item active and add class on it

Tags: reactjs, react-router, menu

I want to add a class to my menu item on click

```
<nav className="pt-4">
        {routes.map(({ icon, name, path }) => (
          <ul  >
            <li key={name} className="mb-1">

              <Link to={`/dashboard${path}`} shallow scroll>

                <a className={`block flex gap-4 items-center px-4 py-2 text-xs hover:pl-6 transition-all duration-300
                ${navigate === path ? 'bg-gradient-to-r from-white/10 text-primary' :
                    'text-white hover:text-primary'
                  }
                `}
                >
                  {icon}
                  <span>{name}</span>
                </a>
              </Link>
            </li>

          </ul>
        ))}
      </nav>
```

I try to use useHistory but it doesn't work anymore and I don't know how to use useNavigate

Comment: What `Link` component are you using? `shallow` and `scroll` are not `react-router` `Link` component props. Please [edit] to include a more complete [mcve] enough to be reproducible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this what works for me :

```js
<NavLink to={`/dashboard${path}`} shallow scroll>
              {({ isActive }) => (

                <a className={`block flex gap-4 items-center px-4 py-2 text-xs hover:pl-6 transition-all duration-300
                ${isActive ? 'bg-gradient-to-r from-white/10 text-primary' :
                    'text-white hover:text-primary'
                  }
                `}
                >
                  {icon}
                  <span>{name}</span>
                </a>
              )}
              </NavLink>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can replace Link component with NavLink component as follows:

```
<NavLink
    to={`/dashboard${path}`}
    className={`block flex gap-4 items-center px-4 py-2 text-xs hover:pl-6 transition-all duration-300 ${(navData) => (navData.isActive ? 'bg-gradient-to-r from-white/10 text-primary' : 'text-white hover:text-primary')}`}
  >
    {icon}
    <span>{name}</span>
</NavLink>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't nest an anchor tag `<a>` within another anchor tag (i.e. the one `Link` is rendering). It's unclear what `Link` component you are importing and using, but I'd suggest using the `NavLink` from `react-router-dom` that takes props that take a callback function that is passed an `isActive` property. The `NavLink` already handles the logic of matching to the "active" route, i.e. the current URL pathname.

Example:

```
<nav className="pt-4">
  <ul>
    {routes.map(({ icon, name, path }) => (
      <li key={name} className="mb-1">
        <NavLink
          to={`/dashboard${path}`}
          className={({ isActive }) => 
            [
              "block flex gap-4 items-center px-4 py-2 text-xs hover:pl-6 transition-all duration-300",
              isActive
                ? "bg-gradient-to-r from-white/10 text-primary"
                : "text-white hover:text-primary"
            ].join(" ")
          }
          end
        >
          {icon}
          <span>{name}</span>
        </NavLink>
      </li>
    ))}
  </ul>
</nav>
```

This is the syntax for the current `react-router-dom@6` component API. If you happen to still be using the older v5 version then the `className` callback is simply passed a boolean value instead of an object.

```
<nav className="pt-4">
  <ul>
    {routes.map(({ icon, name, path }) => (
      <li key={name} className="mb-1">
        <NavLink
          to={`/dashboard${path}`}
          className={isActive => 
            [
              "block flex gap-4 items-center px-4 py-2 text-xs hover:pl-6 transition-all duration-300",
              isActive
                ? "bg-gradient-to-r from-white/10 text-primary"
                : "text-white hover:text-primary"
            ].join(" ")
          }
          exact
        >
          {icon}
          <span>{name}</span>
        </NavLink>
      </li>
    ))}
  </ul>
</nav>
```